# Entity Framework linq on multiple many-to-many entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I am wiriting a document management system using EF Code First. I have 4 entities: User, Usergroup, Document, DocumentType.

I am trying to select the documents which a user has permission to read.
When I try to join the tables using LINQ, I couldn't write a join statement like this because user and userGroup entities are not related directly, there is a hidden mapper table.

```
from u in entities.Users
join ug in entities.UserGroups on u.Id equals ug.userId
```

So how should I make such query with linq? Is there a better way? Or is the architecture bad, and if so how can I make it better?

Here are the entities:

**User:**

```
public class User : BaseModel
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserGroups = new List<UserGroup>();
        this.UserDocumentRevisions = new List<UserDocumentRevision>();
    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(int.MaxValue)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public List<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }

    public List<UserDocumentRevision> UserDocumentRevisions { get; set; }
}
```

**UserGroup:**

```
public class UserGroup : BaseModel
{
    public UserGroup()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
        DocumentTypes = new List<DocumentType>();
    }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public List<DocumentType> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Document:**

```
public class Document : BaseModel
{
    public Document()
    {
        DocumentRevisions = new List<DocumentRevision>();
        DocumentTypes = new List<DocumentType>();
    }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DocumentType> DocumentTypes { get; set; }

    public List<DocumentRevision> DocumentRevisions { get; set; }
}
```

**DocumentType:**

```
public class DocumentType : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public List<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

I am trying to generate this sql, so I can select the documents that a user can read.

```
select distinct d.* from Users u
join UserGroupUsers ugu on u.Id = ugu.User_Id
join UserGroups ug on ugu.UserGroup_Id = ug.Id
join DocumentTypeUserGroups dtug on ug.Id = dtug.DocumentType_Id
join DocumentTypes dt on dtug.DocumentType_Id = dt.Id
join DocumentDocumentTypes ddt on dt.Id = ddt.DocumentType_Id
join Documents d on ddt.Document_Id = d.Id
where u.Id = 1
```

Comment: just join hidden table and then join what you need via direct dependency

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? it would be good to see an example of what are you trying to achieve

Comment: If you are using EF, you should be mapping the hidden table into [Navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and letting EF handle the join.

Comment: How can I join the hidden map table, I dont have an entity for it. So I should write that entity manually right?

Comment: I also added the sql query that I am trying to generate with linq.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place for posts like this